# I need to verify emails when users signup

Tags: email, user-registration

I'm working on my custom plugin and I need to verify the email addresses of users before they can use the platform.

I can do it using regular PHP but I'm having issues doing it with WordPress.

Can someone help with some codes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's any worth, but perhaps you can use the multisite specific activation function, [wpmu_activate_signup](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?q=wpmu_activate_signup&unscoped_q=wpmu_activate_signup), as a reference point to get an idea how to handle verification in WordPress. Multisite uses the special `wp_signups` table to store users waiting for activation. So you might need to create a custom database table, if you want to do something similar.

Another option could be that you assign new users to a custom role, *e.g. user_pending*, and store the activation key to the user meta. Then use `wp_mail()` to send an email with a verification link to the user. And after verification assign the user to proper role. Some kind of cleanup function might be also needed to delete unverified user accounts.